# Firebase fatal exception

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, and I use Firebase for push notifications. When I use a real android phone, after the notification arrives, the app crashes, and the following is written in the log:

> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E
> AndroidRuntime: Process: com.laticrete.mobile, PID: 26667 12-18
> 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:
> android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object 12-18
> 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:   at
> LATICRETE_MobileApp.Droid.Services.FirebaseService.OnMessageReceived
> (Firebase.Messaging.RemoteMessage message) [0x00046] in
> <4b40c62ae78c411d808e657b92d47faa>:0  12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E
> AndroidRuntime:   at
> Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.n_OnMessageReceived_Lcom_google_firebase_messaging_RemoteMessage_
> (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
> native_p0) [0x0000f] in :0  12-18
> 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper
> dynamic-method)
> Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.11(intptr,intptr,intptr)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> crc645f971fb838872db6.FirebaseService.n_onMessageReceived(Native
> Method) 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> crc645f971fb838872db6.FirebaseService.onMessageReceived(FirebaseService.java:30)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.7:80)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.zzh.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.7:2)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
> 12-18 10:37:09.642 26667 26999 E AndroidRuntime:  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

When I debug in Visual Studio, I don't see any issues within OnMessageReceived() override. How can I fix this?

### Update

Here is OnMessageReceived method:

```
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        string messageBody;

        if (message.GetNotification() != null)
        {
            messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;
        }
        else
        {
            messageBody = message.Data.Values.First();
        }

        SendLocalNotification(messageBody);

        if (App.UserContext.IsEmployee)
        {
            App.NewCall(messageBody);
        }
    }
```

And just in case it may help:

```
    public static async void NewCall(string message)
    {
        if (!await CheckVideoCallPermissions())
        {
            return;
        }

        SetLicenseKey();

        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (!IsVideoCallViewOpen)
            {
                var navService = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFreshNavigationService>(FreshMvvm.Constants.DefaultNavigationServiceName);
                Page page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<VideoCallPageModel>();
                await navService.PushPage(page, null);
            }

            VideoCallMessage caller = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoCallMessage>(message);
            VideoCallPeer peer = new VideoCallPeer(caller.UserId, caller.UserName, caller.FirstName);
            OnStartCall?.Invoke(null, peer);
        });
    }
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I provided the log, which makes the problem description very specific. The desired behavior obviously would be not having the specified exception. I don't think it is possible to provide short code to reproduce the issue, as it includes a lot of things to configure, and too much code to place here. Of course this question is for Firebase experts. For an expert, I hope the log may be enough. I am providing the OnMessageReceived() method tough.

Comment: The log tells us that you have a `NullReferenceException` in your `OnMessageReceived`. To find out exactly what is `null`, I recommend setting a breakpoint in that method and stepping through it, checking every value that you call a method or property on.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I am afraid it is not my OnMessageReceived(), but probably the base class' OnMessageReceived(). FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle seems to be very Firebase-specific. When I debug on an emulator, I just don't see anything wrong.

Comment: `LATICRETE_MobileApp.Droid.Services.FirebaseService.OnMessageReceived` does not seem to be a Firebase class to me.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, sure, but I meant base.OnMessageReceived(message); inside of it.

Comment: But again, this doesn't happen in the emulator.

Comment: If you want to know if the exception happened in the OnMessageReceived. You can remove your code in OnMessageReceived and then try again to see if the exception still happen.